# Get the $_POST varaible along with the associated $_FILES

Tags: php, html

I have a form.When a user clicks on add  a file. Two input fields are appended. One with the input name of the file to be uploaded and another with input field for the file itself

```html
<form>
  <label>File 1</label>
  <input type="text" name="fileName[]"/>
  <input type="file" name="file[]"/>
  
  <label>File 2</label>
  <input type="text" name="fileName[]"/>
  <input type="file" name="file[]"/>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

How do i get the corresponding file name and the file together for insertion
Since the text field will be stored in $_POST variable and file in $_FILES

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the answers? I see you have just joined this site. The way StackOverflow works is that feedback goes back and forth until you get grounded on the matters in questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript post request like a form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Answer (score 2):

First your form needs to have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like so:

```
<form type="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

On submit: you can get both $_FILES and $_POST arrays. 
To see what you have, try (if submitted):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

If your file field `name` attribute was "upload_pic", then your `$_FILES` array should look like:

```
Array
(
    [upload_pic] => Array
        (
            [name] => name_of_file
            [type] => file_type
            [tmp_name] => temporary_name
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

I believe that gives you any info you need to insert to DB. (E.g. `$filename = $_FILES['upload_pic']['name']`), add it to the $_POST array and carry on with your insert query.

**EDIT**:
Re-reading your question, I see:

> When a user clicks on add a file. Two input fields are appended. One
>   with the input name of the file to be uploaded and another with input
>   field for the file itself...

I was wondering why you need to manually construct a separate `text` input for the "fileName", since you can obtain it from the `$_FILES` array (as explained above).

Answer (score 0):

Store what is in `$_POST` and what is in `$_FILES` in variables. then you need to open de file with `fopen` and `fwrite` the to the file the variable you retrieved from `$_POST`. Don't forget `fclose` the file when you are done.

Comment: I have  <form type="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> as my form attribute . For each upload Users will be able to  select the category of file he is uploading e.g(Photo, Document, Certificate), Am not looking for the file name itself  But the category the file falls in to. Users add as many as possible. A click on add more button will append two input fields simultaneously (a select box and Input field for the file)
How do i get the corresponding file category Name in the select box and the file together for insertion Since the text field is stored in $_POST variable and file in $_FILES